# Logging commands on cisco devices

Tags: cisco, logging, ios, cisco-catalyst

I'm searching for a way to log every command executed on a cisco switch/router, I have a catalyst 2960s with lanbase image, and a catalyst 4500e with ipbase image.

I've found a way to log commands executed in config mode with the following configuration

```
archive
    log config
     logging enable 100
     notify syslog
     hidekeys
```

but I want to log every command including `show version` for example. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to log the "show" commands themselves into an archive.

You can achieve beyond logging config mode changes using Accounting TACACS+ features (an example with the ASA firewall is shown below, but same concept applies to switches/routers):

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/command/reference/cmd_ref/a1_72.html

> To send accounting messages to the TACACS+ accounting server when you
>   enter any command other than show commands at the CLI, use the aaa
>   accounting command command in global configuration mode.

However, it looks like this CCIE has a workaround if you don't use TACACS+ : http://blog.ipspace.net/2006/11/cli-command-logging-without-tacacs.html -- but the caveat is that you would end up with an "echo" if you leave console logging enabled.